# How to invert Ctrl and Cmd on a Macbook Pro keyboard?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, macbook

using Mac computers for few years, I got accustomed of using the Cmd key on the keyboard as a standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

With Ubuntu 13.04 on my Macbook Pro 5,3 (2009), the Cmd is used for Unity controls, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for applications shortcuts. Is there any way to switch the two keys? So that, as an example, close a tab in Firefox would be Cmd+W instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>?

Comment: Found the answer here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/131900/how-do-i-switch-the-command-key-and-control-key-on-a-macbook-pro-12-04?rq=1 but with 13.04 you must edit an xmodmap file in your /home folder because there is no more a "layout" option in Parameters > System > Keyboard.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, it would be helpful to write up your solution as an answer. If you put your answer on http://askubuntu.com/questions/131900/how-do-i-switch-the-command-key-and-control-key-on-a-macbook-pro-12-04 and edited the question to cover both versions of Ubuntu then this question could be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

I found out a workaround. The solution is to use the xmodmap utility and make it load a personal file with the correct mapping for the keyboard.

1. Open a terminal and create a new file in your /home folder, lets call it `.Xmodmap`

   ```
   nano .Xmodmap
   ```

   (I use nano as a nice text editor inside the console, you can use Gedit instead, install nano with the command *sudo apt-get install nano* if you'd like to test it, it's quite obvious to handle.)
2. Copy/paste the following content to the new file:

   ```
   clear control
   clear mod4

   keycode 105 =
   keycode 206 =

   keycode 133 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
   keycode 134 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
   keycode 37 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L

   add control = Control_L
   add control = Control_R
   add mod4 = Super_L
   ```
3. Make the file executable.

   ```
   chmod +x .Xmodmap
   ```
4. Test it now with the following command:

   ```
   xmodmap .Xmodmap
   ```

   The dash should now appear with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> instead of <kbd>CMD</kbd>, hurra!
5. Now we want the file to be executed each time the system starts up. Open the Startup Applications utility and add a new entry, name it as you want and put the following comand in it:

   ```
   /user/bin/xmodmap /home/YOURUSERNAME/.Xmodmap
   ```

Reboot, it should be ok. If it is not, you should add a `.xinitrc` file in your `/Home` folder, and add the command inside it. The `.xinitrc` file will be read by the system while loading the desktop environment.