# How to cleanly swap alt and ctrl keys in xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout, mac

I have found many answers to this question, but none worked for me.

I'm using xubuntu 15.04.

I'm trying to swap the ctrl and alt keys.

I have tried that :
[How to swap Command and Control keys with xkb step by step?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501659/how-to-swap-command-and-control-keys-with-xkb-step-by-step)

Nothing seems to change.

That, using altwin:ctrl_alt_win :
[How do you remap a key to the Caps Lock key in Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149971/how-do-you-remap-a-key-to-the-caps-lock-key-in-xubuntu)

It works, but only temporary...
So i tried to add alt win:ctrl_alt_win to /etc/default/keyboard and then dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration but nothing changes.

Is there a simple and clean way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this old answer](http://superuser.com/a/364788) on Super User site. It works properly compared to Xmodmap's keycodes method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesnt seems very clean as it is not system wide and doesn't not work after reboot, as it seems that ubuntu doesnt load .Xmodmap. Plus if I follow the instruction and does xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap I get no less than 7306 errors.

Comment: I guess `xmodmap` became obsolete on recent Xubuntu releases (the earlier quoted link still worked for me on Xubuntu 14.04).. You may try [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/347382/37165) or [another one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65600/125388) that suggests `xkb`.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick answer**: instead of `alt win:ctrl_alt_win`, you should use `ctrl:swap_lalt_lctl` to swap alt and ctrl keys.

**Reference**: type `man keyboard`, deep in, and you will find file `/usr/share/doc/keyboard-configuration/xorg.lst` contains options you need.