# Undo a keyboard layout change

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I used to have a Mac keyboard connected to my Ubuntu PC laptop and therefore I switched the Alt and Win keys to match with a regular PC keyboard. I'm not using this keyboard any longer, but I cannot figure out where this change was made.

*/etc/default/keyboard*:

```
XKBLAYOUT="us,us"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBVARIANT=",intl"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="grp_led:scroll"
```

There is no ~/.Xmodmap file

*/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc* isn't changed (according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925330/how-do-i-switch-control-and-alt-option-on-mac-keyboard))

Gnome System -> Preferences -> Keyboard shows *Layout default* for all options

*hid_apple* module isn't loaded

I used to be able to switch back to "PC" mode by issuing the following command, but it's not working on Ubuntu 21.10 anymore. I've just upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04:

`setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_lalt_lwin`

Where else should I look at?

EDIT:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
['altwin:swap_lalt_lwin']
```

Comment: Pls edit your question and show us the output of this terminal command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson thank you, I edited.

Comment: Is `gsetting reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` enough to restore the original layout?

Comment: It probably is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> keys is one of the things one can change through XKB options. The line `XKBOPTIONS` in `/etc/default/keyboard` sets these systemwide. The Gnome Shell desktop can override that with its own dconf setting in `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`.

The setting is not exposed in the user interface, but is available through the Gnome Tweaks utility, Keyboard tab. You can also use `dconf-editor` or a `gsettings` command to access the setting.

By default on Ubuntu, the setting is empty, so you could undo your change with

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```