# Cannot boot Ubuntu after making changes to xkb files

Tags: boot, xkb

So my keyboard's Ctrl button stopped working, I attempted to make edits to xkbd files as in this thread [How to swap ctrl and alt keys in ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885045/how-to-swap-ctrl-and-alt-keys-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Specifically, to the /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ctrl file

Now Ubuntu has an error on boot, "A problem has occured and the system has recovered."
[Erorr screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe6lq.jpg)

Looking for advice on how to get Ubuntu to load now