# Xmodmap keymap on Bluetooth keyboard

Tags: unity, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using a MacBook, and so I wanted to change all CTRl-* shortcuts to use Command instead. I found a nifty Xmodmap file to do this:

```
clear control
clear mod4

keycode 105 =
keycode 206 =

keycode 133 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode 134 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
keycode 37 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L

add control = Control_L
add control = Control_R
add mod4 = Super_L
```

In order to have this apply at boot, I had to run this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false
```

but this sadly made it so that I can no longer change my keyboard input.

Also, I have the issue that when I connect my Apple Wireless Keyboard and use it, it does not use the Xmodmap changes..

Is there a way around disabling org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard? 
Also, I am using the keyboard laungage Englisk (UK, Macintosh), but I have dead keys for " and ', is there a way to turn that off? (Dead keys meaning I have to type space from them to appear).

Thank you.

(Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial, Unity 7.4.0)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by realizing that Xmodmap is not being used anymore, xkb is. So I found this solution:
[How to swap Command and Control keys with xkb step by step?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501659/how-to-swap-command-and-control-keys-with-xkb-step-by-step)

and enabled org.gnome.settings-daemin.plugins.keyboard again (change false to true). 
That makes me able to change my input language. I also tried to use the English (UK, Macintosh) instead of English (UK, Macintosh International) to fix the dead keys - and it is fixed.
It looks like Macintosh International is with dead keys, and simply Macintosh is without!