# Ubuntu 14.04 virtualbox ctrl and alt keys on a MacBook Pro keyboard?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mac

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro and I installed VirtualBox 4.3.28 for OS X hosts  x86/amd64. I then installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 and the Virtualbox extensions.

I want to use the Ctrl and Alt keys in a similar way as I would find them in a regular PC laptop with respect to the spacebar:

```
[ Control_L ] [ Alt ] [        Spacebar        ] [ Control_R ]
```

This is what I usually use in my regular PC laptops in the past, so my brain got used to the keyboard layout, where I basically lean my left thumb on <kbd>Alt</kbd> and my right thumb on the <kbd>R_Ctrl<'kbd> key.</kbd>

EDITED:

I found an answer to a similar question where they describe how to change the Mac <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd> keys. This gets me closer to what I want, with the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key now working: [How do I switch the Command key and Control key on a MacBook Pro?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131900/how-do-i-switch-the-command-key-and-control-key-on-a-macbook-pro)

> Put the following in `~/.Xmodmap`:
>
> ```
> clear control
> clear mod4
>
> keycode 105 =
> keycode 206 =
>
> keycode 133 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
> keycode 134 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
> keycode 37 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
>
> add control = Control_L
> add control = Control_R
> add mod4 = Super_L
> ```
>
> To test, run the command:
>
> ```
> xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
> ```

What I want to do now is to complete the modification by swapping the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and Alt buttons around. But I don't know how to do that with `xmodmap`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my issue:

```
clear control
clear mod4
clear mod1

keycode 105 =
keycode 206 =

keycode 64 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode 133 = Alt_L NoSymbol Alt_L
keycode 134 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
keycode 37 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L

add control = Control_L
add control = Control_R
add mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L
add mod4 = Super_L
```

If using an external keyboard plugged to the mac laptop, you can also map the keyboard in the list of available inputs in your Ubuntu instance by defining it in `Settings -> Text Entry -> Input Sources` as shown below (for a UK laptop). After that, you can switch between keyboards with the top-left corner icon (if on Metacity), e.g. `En1`:

[image: Keyboard setup]