# How to map the spacebar to Ctrl while still preserving the original behavior?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've tried setting `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources` to `['space:ctrl']` but it doesn't work.

Note: I want the spacebar to keep working as before (Space should trigger both Ctrl and Space, I don't mind the conflict).

Comment: Please show us the exact command you used.

Comment: Did it via dconf-editor, these are the exact values I used.

Comment: What's the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`?

Comment: I tested, and it didn't work for me either. Probably it's not a valid `xkb-options` value. You can run `localectl list-x11-keymap-options` to view a list of valid values.

Comment: You wanted _Space should trigger both Ctrl and Space_, but what it should do for shortcuts which needs combination of Ctrl and Space? Not at least with preserving the original behaviour. What I understand from the question is, you wanted the space to act like Ctrl when you want it and like Space, when you don't. That's not possible now

Comment: @Anwar You misunderstood: I don't mind the conflict since I never use Ctrl and Space together.

Comment: This is a very good good question.  Me just looking up different ideas https://github.com/r0adrunner/Space2Ctrl https://github.com/alols/xcape

Answer (score 1):

From a terminal run:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 65=Control_R'
```

To undo, type:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 65=space'
```

In general, to see the list of all keysyms that you can map and their names, type:

```
xmodmap -pk
```

Comment: Not working for me on Ubuntu 16.04. Tried mapping both Control_R and Control_L but the usual shortcuts aren't working in any application. Also I'd like for the spacebar to still work as before, I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: Mmm, does [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11184) or [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/158014/308164) answer help?