# Broken Ctrl and Command keys

Tags: unity, 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I attempted to remap my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key as Command, to behave the same as OSX. I created an [`~/.Xmodmap` as suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131900/how-do-i-switch-the-command-key-and-control-key-on-a-macbook-pro)

It worked great until I restarted (after system update). Now, neither key responds at all in most apps.

I removed the .Xmodmap file, as well as `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*` and `setxkbmap -layout us` to undo the changes I made. Still no luck

Any idea how to fix this? Or reset back to default?

I also notice the shortcut suggestions missing from the dropdown menu bar e.g. `Edit > Copy/Paste`