# Configuring a Mac Magic keyboard

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I own a Lenovo Thinkpad T440p running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with an AZERTY keyboard and I would like to improve the usage of my external Mac Magic keyboard (AZERTY as well, no numpad).

While the existing Mac text entry setting works for most of the keys, there are still a few issues I do not know how to fix:

- Cmd+C or Cmd+V should work as the built-in keyboard's Ctrl+C (copy) or Ctrl+V (paste)
- keypress on Magic keyboard key < actually types @
- keypress on Magic keyboard key > actually types #
- keypress on Magic keyboard key @ actually types <
- keypress on Magic keyboard key # actually types >

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to select the corresponding keyboard layout.

Comment: Your chance to get help increases if you tell us which keyboard layout you use and which keys you have a problem with.

Comment: Isn't it in the initial description?
Built-in keyboard: Thinkpad T440 AZERTY Keyboard.
USB Keyboard: Magic Macintosh AZERTY keyboard without numpad.

Comment: @MichaelBay : refined my initial question

Comment: Few helpers here know all the details about all keyboards out there. ;) Anyway, I posted an answer which hopefully helps partially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partial answer is to make use of the `apple:badmap` XKB option.

Terminal command to satisfy the Mac keyboard:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['apple:badmap']"
```

Terminal command to disable the option:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

As regards making Command/Ctrl I think this question applies:

[How do I switch the Command key and Control key on a MacBook Pro?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131900/how-do-i-switch-the-command-key-and-control-key-on-a-macbook-pro)

Comment: @Rolf: Good, that's what I hoped. I added a link to my answer to cover the Cmd/Ctrl part of the question.