# Magic keyboard with ubuntu - option and command is mapped incorrectly

Tags: keyboard, apple

I am using the apple magic keyboard with Ubuntu 21.10 on a carbon x1.

[image]

I can connect and almost everything is perfect. However, the super and alt key is switched incorrectly. When I press the "Option" key on this keyboard ALT key is activated. When I press "Command" key on this keyboard Command key is activated.

Going into the keyboard settings and "View keyboard layout" confirms that this is some weird behavior. Here is an image, I press the middle key "option" but the right command key is highlighted in the software:

[image]

How can I remap these keys, without them affecting the keyboard on the laptop itself? I would love your help.

Comment: You should upgrade to 21.10 first, since 21.04 is now EOL (and thus off-topic here).

Comment: Option is supposed to be Alt, AFAIK (see, e.g. [this Apple doc](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)).

Comment: @ArturMeinild Updated OS. still not working.

Comment: @muru thank you. I see what you mean. It's still weird to me though and I would like it fixed. I added a picture to hopefully make it clear

Comment: You might want to try https://askubuntu.com/a/1052775/158442 with one of the options in [the Ctrl section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx9Aj.png)

Comment: @muru thank you! Your suggestion about using tweak tools helped me. Can you please make an "answer" comment with this tweak tool settings that did the trick? https://imgur.com/a/TDwJTDw 
so you can get your well deserved credit

Comment: Actually forgot all about it should only work for the keyboard. Tweak tools also update the laptops own keyboard sadly